# JSF: javax.faces.resources is not referenced in my application

Tags: java, jsf, resources

`Resources` folder containing `js` and `css` file from `javax.faces.resource` is not referenced in my application, here is the front end errorlog that i get using `Chrome` developer tools

```
GET http://demo:2008/javax.faces.resource/themes/sam/theme.css.jsp?ln=icefaces.ace 404 (Not Found)
JobImport.jsp:246GET http://demo:2008/javax.faces.resource/util/ace-components.js.jsp?ln=icefaces.ace 404 (Not Found)
JobImport.jsp:246GET http://demo:2008/javax.faces.resource/yui/yui-min.js.jsp?ln=yui/3_1_1&v=3068887 404 (Not Found)
JobImport.jsp:246GET http://demo:2008/javax.faces.resource/util/combined.css.jsp?ln=icefaces.ace 404 (Not Found)
JobImport.jsp:246GET http://demo:2008/javax.faces.resource/loader/loader-min.js.jsp?ln=yui/3_1_1&v=3068887 404 (Not Found)
JobImport.jsp:246GET http://demo:2008/javax.faces.resource/util/ace-jquery.js.jsp?ln=icefaces.ace 404 (Not Found)
JobImport.jsp:246GET http://demo:2008/javax.faces.resource/yui2-skin-sam-button/assets/button-core.css.jsp?ln=yui/2in3 404 (Not Found)
JobImport.jsp:246GET http://demo:2008/javax.faces.resource/combined.js.jsp?ln=org.icefaces.component.util&v=3068887 404 (Not Found)
JobImport.jsp:246GET http://demo:2008/javax.faces.resource/yui2-skin-sam-tabview/assets/tabview-core.css.jsp?ln=yui/2in3 404 (Not Found)
JobImport.jsp:246GET http://demo:2008/javax.faces.resource/combined.css.jsp?ln=org.icefaces.component.util 404 (Not Found)
JobImport.jsp:246GET http://demo:2008/javax.faces.resource/fileEntry.js.jsp?ln=org.icefaces.component.fileentry&v=3068887 404 (Not Found)
JobImport.jsp:246GET http://demo:2008/javax.faces.resource/slider/assets/slider-core.css.jsp?ln=yui/3_1_1 404 (Not Found)
JobImport.jsp:246GET http://demo:2008/javax.faces.resource/bridge.js.jsp?v=3068887 404 (Not Found)
JobImport.jsp:246GET http://demo:2008/javax.faces.resource/icefaces-compat.js.jsp 404 (Not Found)
JobImport.jsp:246GET http://demo:2008/javax.faces.resource/compat.js.jsp 404 (Not Found)
JobImport.jsp:246GET http://demo:2008/javax.faces.resource/jsf.js.jsp?ln=javax.faces&v=3068887 404 (Not Found)
JobImport.jsp:249Uncaught ReferenceError: ice is not defined
(anonymous function)JobImport.jsp:249
JobImport.jsp:250Uncaught ReferenceError: ice is not defined
(anonymous function)JobImport.jsp:250
JobImport.jsp:253Uncaught ReferenceError: ice is not defined
JobImport.jsp:254Uncaught ReferenceError: ice is not defined
```

Is there any particular configuration that we need to do so that `javax.faces.resources` are properly referenced in our application?

**Updates : Added jsp, xhtml and web.xml files**

Here is my `jsp` page

```
    <html>
<head>
    <!-- BEGIN SCRIPT TO OPEN RIGHT NOW HELP POPUP, THIS SCRIPT INCLUDES THE FUNCTION OPENRN-->
    <%@ include file="/js/popupRightNow.inc" %>

    <!-- END SCRIPT TO OPEN RIGHT NOW HELP POPUP, THIS SCRIPT INCLUDES THE FUNCTION OPENRN-->
    <title>Test</title>

    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
</head>
<body>
<jsp:include page="/navigation/TopNav.jsp" flush="true"/>

<jsp:include page="/entry/Upload.xhtml"/>


<!--BEGIN BOTTOM NAV -->
<jsp:include page="/navigation/BottomNav.jsp" flush="true"/>
<!--END BOTTOM NAV -->
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my `xhtml` page:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
```

```
<h:head>
    <title>ICEfaces 3</title>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/xmlhttp/css/rime/rime.css"/> -->
</h:head>
<h:body>
         <h:form id="form">
            <h:outputText value="Welcome to ICEfaces 3, select current date: "/>
            <ace:dateTimeEntry renderAsPopup="true">
                <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" timeZone="Canada/Mountain"/>
            </ace:dateTimeEntry>
            <ace:fileEntry id = "fileUpload"
                           label="File Entry"
                           relativePath="uploaded"
                           fileEntryListener="#{fileUpload.uploadFile}"/>
         <h:commandButton value="Upload File" />
         </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Here is my `web.xml`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app >
 <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
<param-name>javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS</param-name>
<param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
<param-name>com.icesoft.faces.concurrentDOMViews</param-name>
<param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
<param-name>com.icesoft.faces.synchronousUpdate</param-name>
<param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
<param-name>com.icesoft.faces.blockingRequestHandler</param-name>
<param-value>icefaces</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
<param-name>com.icesoft.faces.checkJavaScript</param-name>
<param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>

  <!-- filters.xml : Non-XDoclet filter declarations, merged into web.xml by XDoclet. -->



    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/xmlhttp/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

Comment: Any thoughts, suggestions? Let me know if there is need to add more  material to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got some mess with your URLs and servlet mappings. You have requested your JSF page with suffix .jsp. As a consequence all resource requests reuse this prefix:

GET http://demo:2008/javax.faces.resource/util/ace-components.js.**jsp**?ln=icefaces.ace

My guess is you have somehow mapped the original request to the faces servlet but the subsequent resource requests fail to match the mapping pattern.

I recommend two things: don't use .jsp as an extension for JSF page requests. Make it .jsf or something else unused. Then make sure you've got proper servlet mapping, mapping this extension to the faces servlet:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Thing here is in my jsp page, am calling xhtml page and jsp are compiled in our build process and so i guess my mappings are correct, i guess.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not understand your comment. Maybe if you posted web.xml and what URL was requested here it would make things more clear.

Comment: Please see my updates, i have added web.xml, jsp and xhtml for reference.

Comment: You are including a full xhtml page in a jsp page. Maybe it is doable but looks risky to say the least. Any particular reason you want to mix jsp and xhtml this way?

Comment: I need to include those header/footer stuffs that we have on jsp and so am including my xhtml page inside jsp, not sure how to get header/footer in my xhtml page.

Comment: I would experiment with converting your main jsp page to xhtml and trying to include header/footer from there. My experience with this kind of integration is limited though so perhaps someone else will give a better advice.

Comment: This is the issue am having and am not able to figure it out.

Comment: i don't use .jsp as an extension for JSF page requests or explicitly map them then why do i get this kind of issues with ace-jquery.js.jsp extensions?

Comment: I recommend asking another question: whether it's possible to include xhtml in a jsp page. I have never tried such thing myself. If it's not possible, just have to translate your jsp pages into xhtml and display it as single-technology page.