# JSF scripts not loading on different environment

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, icefaces, icefaces-3

I've deployed a jsf 2.1 / Icefaces 3.3 application on my local WebSphere app server. The javascript resources added automatically by JSF for example as below loads in the local windows environment but not in a remote app server on Linux environment.

```
<script src="/myAppContext/javax.faces.resource/jsf.js.faces?ln=javax.faces" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The same thing would work for a different app but not this. I may be doing something wrong somewhere but I don't know where to start with?

**EDIT:**

[image]

Comment: What does the HTTP traffic monitor say? Press F12 in Chrome/FF>=23/IE>=9 and check *Network* tab. Does the browser get HTTP 2nn/3nn response on them or something different?

Comment: The local js/css resources are loaded, except the ones generated by jsf and icefaces (please seee edit). The web server used on the domain is IBM_HTTP_Server.

Comment: Okay, the problem is clearly in the server side. It's strange that this is environment-specific. Perhaps you've an overzealous servlet filter which does things based on environmental specifics?

Comment: Not at all! No filters used. Does web server come into play?

Comment: Well, it returned 404. Client can't do anything against it. So definitely a server side problem. It'll probably be again ICEfaces related. See also this similar Q&A which is incorrectly been marked accepted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10078330/jsf-javax-faces-resources-is-not-referenced-in-my-application The OP never confirmed that the answer 
worked.

Comment: Actually I have several apps deployed to the same environment and exactly same libs and configuration in web.xml, those apps don't have any issue.

Comment: It's apparently a corrupted deploy.

Comment: I already mapped `FacesServlet` to `.xhtml`, `.jsf`, `/icefaces/*`, `/faces/*`, `.faces`

Comment: But I think you are right, it may be a corrupted deploy. Let me try clean and redeploy on the server.

Comment: Redeployed app but no luck!